# How to animate alignment from top to bottom on hover?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm looking for a way to animate a hover transition with css. And I'm hoping to keep it pure css. If not I'll use jquery as backup.

**This would be my goal:**

A container with a content div. And when hovering it would animate / slide up. As illustrated:
[image]

I've tried something like the code below. Problem is than transition does not animate the `auto` part. The content has a variable height. So it differs each time. (per grid item)

```
    .my_container{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 160%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .my_container > .my_content{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }


    .my_container > my_content:hover{
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .my_container * {
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    }
```

I thought about `transform: translateY();` But as far as I know this only works with percentages and px.

**The goal is to animate it aligned top to bottom on hover.**

(typing this made me think of another thing. This would be useless on a mobile device, right? :) )

Comment: In mobile devices, tap action will trigger hover state

Comment: You have an error, a missing dot in the second `.my_container > .my_content` block. And I don't see any `:hover`. Is this the real CSS?

Comment: As you already said, it only works with `px or %`, not with `auto`. You could use jQuery maybe?

Comment: @Duannx, ah that's great

Comment: @MrLister, :) yes, forgot the `:hover`. It is a simplified version of my code yes

Comment: @Refilon hmm I really hoped to keep it with css. jQuery won't be a problem. Just preferred it this way

Comment: Alright, you know what? I'll go with jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case there is a known relation between the child and parent element you can then easily apply translation.

Here is a basic example

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
  margin:50px;
  border:3px solid;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:143%;
  background:red;
  transition:1s all;
}
.box:hover::before {
  transform:translateY(-30%) 
  /* 143% is 100%
     100% is X% ---> X = 70% so we move by (100% - 70%)
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can express with a CSS variable:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
  margin:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:3px solid;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(var(--p)*1%);
  background:red;
  transition:1s all;
}
.box:hover::before {
  transform:translateY(calc((10000/var(--p))*1% - 100%)) 
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:143;">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--p:170;">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--p:120;">

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

In case of dynamic content you can add small JS code like below:

```js
$('.box').each(function() {
  var h0 = $(this).height();
  var h1 = $(this).find('span').height();
  
  $(this).css('--t',(h0-h1));
})
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.box:hover span{
  transform: translateY(var(--t));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est ex, pretium tempus turpis vitae, </span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est ex, pretium </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoa, that's pretty sweet. One thing though, I found a huge error in my own explanation on the matter. The inner content has a variable height. It depends on the length of the text per grid item.

Comment: @Tim I knwon ;) I simply gave a solution in case you have a height set using percentage as I don't think there is an easy generic solution with pure CSS

Comment: Yeah, I though so. I'll be going with jquery then. With that I can also think about conditional behaviors on different devices.

Comment: :) I didn't see your edit. Nice. neat and clean. I like it. Thanks! Very elaborative.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `jQuery` approach. It compares the size of the container and the content. And if it's bigger than the container it animates the difference up so it all comes visible.

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.post_grid_item').hover(

        function() {

            $containter = $(this).find('.content_slide');
            $content = $(this).find('.content_slide > .vce-row-content');

            $content_height    = $content.outerHeight();
            $containter_height = $containter.outerHeight() ;

            // if content is bigger than container
            if( $content_height >  $containter_height ) {

                $content_hover_offset = $containter_height - $content_height;

                $content.animate({
                    top: $content_hover_offset + 'px',
                }, 'fast');
            }

        },function() {

            $containter = $(this).find('.content_slide');
            $content = $(this).find('.content_slide > .vce-row-content');

            $content.animate({
                top: '0',
            },'fast');
        }
    );


});
```

This would give me some more conditional flexibility when adding specific mobile device conditions.

If anyone sees some improvements let me know.